# Sharepoint web service throwing Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am coding for consuming Sharepoint 2010 web services in Java using Netbeans. I am able to creating the web service client from WSDL using the provided wizard. When I call the following code I get the `Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException`

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;

import proxy.webs.GetWebCollectionResponse;
import proxy.webs.GetWebResponse;
import proxy.webs.Webs;
import proxy.webs.WebsSoap;

public class AccessLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String username = "domain\\Administrator";
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
        NtlmAuthenticator ntlmAuth = new NtlmAuthenticator(username, password);
        Authenticator.setDefault(ntlmAuth);

        Webs websService = new Webs(new URL("http://servername:7766/_vti_bin/Webs.asmx?wsdl"));
        WebsSoap webPort = websService.getWebsSoap();
        GetWebResponse.GetWebResult webRes = webPort.getWeb("http://servername/sites/Test1");
        System.out.println(webRes);
    }
}
```

The site `http://servername/sites/Test1` exists and I can open it in the browser.

Update 1: Similar thing happens for C# code, which I run on the same machine as Sharepoint 2010:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Webs webService = new Webs();
            webService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            Object o = webService.GetWeb("http://servername/sites/Test1");
            Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this is the problem with the set up and not with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong endpoint for the web service. For the Sharepoint site `http://servername/sites/Test1` the endpoint should also be `http://servername/sites/Test1/_vti_bin/Webs.asmx?wsdl`